# Problem with \tableofcontents facility in amsbook environment

Tags: table-of-contents, amsbook

The  \tableofcontents facility in amsbook is overprinting section numbers on top of the first few letters of the section title in the table of contents. What to do? BTW, I'm indicating the separate sections within each chapter file with the \section{name of section} command.

Comment: This is a known bug.  An add-on package has been developed for making adjustments, but it isn't posted publicly because the ideal solution is really to fix the bug.  However, there is no prohibition against sending a copy on request; send your request to tech-support@ams.org .

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please add always a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op hasn't been seen for many months, and no example was given.